# JQuery UI datepicker within rails nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very beginner to ruby on rails and web-development.

I created my app that similar to Ryan Bates, episode 197 and 198, but with use JQuery UI datepicker. But I dont really know how to do that. I know that the problem is with element ID always same whatever I generated new dynamic partial.
For example, when I choose a day, it works fine. but when I add new nested model (or record), only the first nested model change.

I use ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.1, I must use thses versions.

Please I was struggling with this. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.datePicker').each(function() {
$(this).datepicker();
});
</script>
<div class ="fields">
  <%= f.select(:assessmethods_id,@types,:include_blank=>true) %>  
  <%= f.text_field(:assessdate,:class => "datePicker") %>
  <%= link_to_remove_fields("remove", f) %>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you got any error? if you have any then post here. In above code you missed out end script tag.

Comment: Thank you Arun for your notice. Yes I got end script tag in my code.

Comment: Look here to see my stab at the solution.  I used the advice on this article to help me solve it. 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16013174/913451    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700248/rails-3-nested-form-jquery-datepicker-wont-load-when-add-a-task/16013174#16013174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('.datePicker').datepicker();
});
</script>
<div class ="fields">
  <%= f.select(:assessmethods_id,@types,:include_blank=>true) %>  
  <%= f.text_field(:assessdate,:class => "datePicker") %>
  <%= link_to_remove_fields("remove", f) %>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to call each on the selected elements, since that's more expensive than just calling it out right. $('.datePicker').datepicker(); should work.