# Reload calendar into nested forms (rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a form which contains one model (let's call it Model1) and this models accepts nested attributes from another one (let's call it Model2). I want to be able to save many Model2 records, but I want the view, at the beginning, to show just one set of fields from Model2, and have a button which, if clicked, displays another set of fields from that model, and so on. For this, i'm using the [nested_form gem](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form).

All is working well, but the problem is that one of the fields is associated with a datepicker. So, the first Model2 set of fields shows the calendar, but when I click to render the next set of fields, the datepicker, of course, does not get shown anymore (because the Javascript loads only when you get to the page and never again)

The following code shows the button which adds more concepts (Concept is Model2)

```
<%= f.fields_for :concepts do |concept_form| %>
<%= render "courses/concept_fields", :f=>concept_form%>
<% end %>

<p><%= f.link_to_add t("concepts.add"), :concepts %></p>
```

And inside courses/concept_fields I have:

```
<%= f.text_field :collection_date, :value => f.object.collection_date, :class => 'text date_picker tabs' %>
```

The javascript for the datepicker is included in the layout

Is there any way you can help me? Thanks!

Comment: please share the code for the button which adds more fields for Model2 and where you initiate the datepicker

Comment: I've update my post. It now contains some code which answer your doubts. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add and click event handler to the button you use to render the next set of fields to reload the datepicker something like:

```
$('.render_next_button').click(function(){
   // code to reload datepicker
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer which solved my problem. It's in this link:

[jQuery UI DatePicker with nested_forms Gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576390/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-nested-forms-gem)

Would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('form').live('nested:fieldAdded', function(event) {
        jQuery(event.field).find('.date_picker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();
    });
});

</script>
```