# Adding a date picker to a nested form field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, calendar, nested-forms

I am trying to add the jquery-ui date picker to my application's nested form fields, however when I update the DOM with the new fields I do not get the date picker to show up on the fields that were created. Here is the code that I have working for the application.

```
<%= form_for(@load) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <%= f.fields_for :destinations do |builder| %>
    <%= render "destination_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields " Add Destination", f, :destinations %></p> 
<% end %> 

_destination_fields.html.erb
============================
<fieldset>
  <%= f.text_field :arrival_date, :placeholder => "From:", :class => "datepicker" %>
</fieldset>
```

The coffeescript for adding fields:

```
jQuery ->

    $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
        time = new Date().getTime()
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
        $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
        event.preventDefault()
```

The function for adding fields:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields btn btn-primary icon-plus", data: { id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n",""), :class => "datepicker" })
end
```

The javascript I have written to show the datepicker:

```
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', autoSize:true });
});

$(function() {
    $('.add_fields').on('click', function(){
      $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', autoSize:true });
    });
});
```

I have seen other solutions for this problem on stack overflow but none of their implementations have worked for my problem. As you can see the javascript checks for any field with the "datepicker" class on it and then adds the datepicker class to it. I am pretty sure you need to add a callback function to the button that adds new fields when it is clicked, which is what I have done, but I am unsure why my function is not working properly. If you need any more information to help solve this problem I will gladly provide it.

## Solution Edit:

I changed the coffeescript file to the following to make this work as expected:

```
 jQuery ->
   datepicker_update = -> $("input.datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', autoSize:true })

  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
    datepicker_update()
```

This was a combination answer from the two provided below

Comment: typo datpicker in link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields btn btn-primary icon-plus", data: { id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n",""), :class => "datpicker" })

Comment: Fixed the typo, but that only affects the data-class of the button and not the input field I am trying to target.

Comment: ok so i am not sure what your link does, but in the js click function you attach the dtepicker to the link tag not to text fields.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, and I have confirmed it using the focus(); method on this. I need to figure out a way to target the correct field.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, but it was close.  Look here to see my stab at the solution.  I used the advice on this article to help me solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700248/rails-3-nested-form-jquery-datepicker-wont-load-when-add-a-task/16013174#16013174

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback on the click event for the '.add_fields' button is a step in the right direction. It's a little hard for me to tell with your template code and not clear HTML but the following appears to be the problem:

```
$(function() {
    $('.add_fields').on('click', function(){
      //Below $(this) refers to $('.add_fields'). I assume that is a button and is not what you want to apply the datepicker to. 
      $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', autoSize:true });
    });
});
```

You're trying to apply the datepicker to $('.add_fields'). What I normally do is I create a datepicker_update function as follows:

```
function datepicker_update(){
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', autoSize:true });
}
```

Then whenever I update the DOM with new date fields I make sure I give them the .datepicker class and then I call datepicker_update() which finds any .datepicker fields and turns them into datepickers. You may want to include a test to see if a given field already has datepicker applied although I believe jQuery UI might already do that?

Futhermore, it's best to include the datepicker_update and the process of adding fields in one event callback otherwise it can lead to timing issues where you're trying to update datepickers for fields that haven't quite made it into the DOM yet. Make sure your code is executing in the correct sequence...perhaps try using some console.logs to check.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I got it to work by altering my coffeescript file because that is where is click event is handled. Here is the code for making it work:  datepicker_update = -> $("input.datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', autoSize:true }) then calling datepicker_update() after event.preventDefault

Answer (score 1):

Listening to `click` may sometime not work since custom listener and nested form listener works concurrently. Our custom listener may finish before nested form. In that case last added field will not get processed.

So instead of using below code

```
 $('.add_fields').on('click', function(){
```

use `fieldAdded` event triggered by nested form like below,

```
  $(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
    // this field was just inserted into your form
     $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', autoSize:true });
  })
```

Check [here](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form#javascript-events) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.add_fields').on('click', function(){
      $('input.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', autoSize:true });
    });
});
```